# Curl is failing to connect to StartCom protected sites while wget succeeds

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to track down a strange issue with my servers.  Within the last day or so, connections to certain SSL protected sites(both HTTP and SMTP) started failing.

Here is the output from openssl:

> CONNECTED(00000003) depth=1 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure
>   Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Class 2 Primary
>   Intermediate Server CA verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer
>   certificate verify return:0

This is only affecting servers which are protected by startcom certificates, and has only started happening in the last few days.  I verified that the StartCom certificates are installed in /etc/ssl/certs and they are the ones I need.

What makes this really bizarre is that using wget succeeds and curl fails.  This is on Debian Jessie.

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work - openssl or curl?

Comment: It appears the openssl is the culprit, but I'm not sure why wget works and only StartCom certificates are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.  I somehow corrupted my CA directory.  Deleting /etc/ssl/certs and then running *apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates* fixed it.